# Why this pattern is not matched

Tags: erlang

Hi I am new to Erlang and have tried the below code in Pattern Matching. As expected it does not work for me, Someone please help me to understand this concept better

```
1> Prat = {name,{{first,prat},{last,redy}},{age,23},occupation,{{company,"TS"},{work, "SW"}}}
2> {_,{_,_},_,_,{{_,c},_}} = Prat
```

But it returns me unmatched error. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this expression, `"{_,{_,_},_,_,{{_,c},_}} = Prat"`, c is a variable, should be capitalized.
`{_,{_,_},_,_,{{_,C},_}} = Prat`.

C = "TS".

Comment: Thank you so much. Hmmm silly mistake but great experience :-)